# Function to concatenate first name and last name in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

How to write a function to concatenate first name and last name of an employee, passing employee id as an input to the function `CONCAT_NAME`. The code which I tried is-

```
set serveroutput on;
    create or replace function concat_name(v_id employee.emp_id%type)
    return varchar2(25)
    is
    begin
    select (first_name || last_name) into concat_name from employee where emp_id = v_id;
    dbms_output.put_line(concat_name);
    end;
    /
```

The expected output is -

```
{CONCAT_NAME(101)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SmithWilliam
SmithWilliam}
```

But the error running the above is-

```
Warning: Function created with compilation errors.
SELECT CONCAT_NAME(101) FROM EMPLOYEE
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06575: Package or function CONCAT_NAME is in an invalid state
```

Any help would be very thankful!

Comment: run `show errors` to see the details on the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not like that. Functions have one specific reason why they exist: to **return** a value. So - `return` it, don't `dbms_output.put_line` it. Certainly, you should use correct syntax as well. I suggest you read documentation first, code next.

I'm in love with 10g's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/pls/db102/homepage) because its homepage is nicely divided into useful sections. Have a look at the **Most Popular** list of books, and read

- Application Developer's Guide - Fundamentals
- PL/SQL User's Guide and Reference

as they cover PL/SQL you're currently learning. I presume you do know SQL; if not, well, read that book first. Also, now that you know *what* to read, feel free to find documentation related to your database version.

---

As of your task:

```
SQL> create or replace function concat_name(v_id employee.emp_id%type)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    retval varchar2(25);
  5  begin
  6    select first_name || last_name
  7      into retval
  8      from employee
  9      where emp_id = v_id;
 10
 11    return retval;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> select concat_name(101) from dual;

CONCAT_NAME(101)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SmithWilliam

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution as well as the study material, I'll surely go through it.